# Django Forms: Hidden model field?

Tags: django

I've got a `Form`. I want to include a hidden field that returns a model. I'll set it's value in the view; I just need it to be posted along to the next page.

What field am I supposed to use in the form class?

Answer (score 29):

A hidden field that returns a model? So a model instance ID?

The `forms.HiddenInput` widget should do the trick, whether on a FK field or CharField you put a model instance ID in.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    hidden_2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    hidden_css = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MostWidgets(attrs={'style': 'display:none;'}))
```

I suppose the fastest way to get this working is

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    model_instance = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput())

form = MyForm({'model_instance': '1'})
form.cleaned_data['model_instance']
```

But I don't like the idea of supplying MyModel.objects.all() if you're going to specify one item anyways.

It seems like to avoid that behavior, you'd have to override the form `__init__` with a smaller `QuerySet`.

I think I prefer the old fashioned way:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    model_instance = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean_model_instance(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['model_instance']
        if not data:
            raise forms.ValidationError()
        try:
            instance = MyModel.objects.get(id=data)
        except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError()
        return instance
```

Comment: Don't think `ForeignKey` is a valid form field... it's a model field. I'd rather it return a model instance rather than an integer (when I retrieve it later with `form.cleaned_data['field']`)

Comment: forms.MostWidgets? meaning most of available widgets?

Comment: @fanny yeah, you should be able to simply hide the widget by setting the  style attribute, but `HiddenInput()` makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

The approach in Yuji's answer uses a `clean_model_instance` method on the form which is fine if you're only ever doing this once in your code base. If you do it more often, then you might benefit from implementing a custom model field.

This is the code I have:

```py
from django import forms

class ModelField(forms.Field):

    Model = None

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        """Inject entities' id value into the form's html data"""
        if isinstance(value, self.Model):
            return value.id
        return value

    def to_python(self, value):
        """More or less stolen from ModelChoiceField.to_python"""

        if value in self.empty_values:
            return None

        try:
            value = self.Model.objects.get(id=value)
        except (ValueError, self.Model.DoesNotExist):
            raise forms.ValidationError('%s does not exist'
                                         % self.Model.__class__.__name__.capitalize())

        return value
```

If you use that as a base class and then specialise it with your own models then it becomes a useful based. For example:

```py
# In app/fields.py
from .models import CustomModel

class CustomModelField(ModelField):

    Model = CustomModel
```

Then you can pair that with whatever widget you need at the time:

```py
# in app/forms.py
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    hidden_custom_model_field = CustomModelField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    other_widget_custom_model_field = CustomModelField(widget=MyCustomWidget())
```